# Navigation grid inside of a FormView

Tags: c#, gridview, formview

We have a list of elements we use to drive a form view.  Typically the resultset is between 5-15 records.  Right now in the form view we have the typical first/prior/next/last for navigation.  The problem is that sometimes the user needs to go directly to a specific record to edit it.  The records here are job tasks that have some pretty short descriptions.

The idea was proposed to put a gridview inside of the formview that lists all of the records for that form, and a user can just select view or edit on that record and it will navigate directly to that record and put it into the proper mode.  We could put this outside the form view as well, that doesn't really matter.

The question is, regardless of the dirving force, how to I tell the formview to go to record X driven from something like an external grid.

I know that the formview has the DataKeyNames field but is there a way to say "Go to record who's PK is 17" given that it's in the current dataset for the formview?

If so, does anyone have any sample C# code for it?  I know we could just populate the existing formview with a single record, but we also want to keep the normal navigation buttons in place as well, in the event as well (sometimes there's cases where there's hundreds of job tasks, in which case we'd supress the grid view -- sounds wrong but there's more to the business case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This short solution was to embed the grid in the FormView ItemTemplate and reference the same data source for both.

To made the row editable, you need a simple callback for RowDataBound on the grid in which you will retrive the link button (or whatever control you're using to trigger the edit) and then set the command argument to the rowindex.  After that, you need to have the callback for the link button (or trigger) that wil retrieve the command argument (again the row index) and then set the FormView PageIndex to that value, and then set the ChangeMode for the FormView to FormViewMode.Edit.

So to recap, for read only view it's a grid with all of the items, but when handle the edit or insert, you get the traditional form view.